# Postgres - How to join on two columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table containing account information:

[image]

And another table, containing transactions information:

[image]

I'd like to retrieve both the titles from transactions.from_acc_id and transactions.to_acc_id

So far, I'm only able to retrieve either one or the other with the following JOIN:

```
SELECT transactions.transaction_type, 
transactions.from_acc_id, 
transactions.to_acc_id,
transactions.amount,
account.title AS "ACCOUNT DESTINATION"
FROM transactions
JOIN account 
ON transactions.to_acc_id = account.acc_id
```

[image]

This gives me the title of transactions.to_acc_id.

How can I add another field containing the title of transactions.from_acc_id with the same SELECT statement, please ?

Thanks

EDIT: I'd like to keep all field from the Select statement, adding the title of transactions.from_acc_id where is pertinent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You join your account table in twice and give each instance its own alias. Furthermore, to ensure that every record from `transactions` table shows up and only those records from your `accounts` table (both source and destination), use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of your implicit `INNER JOIN` that you are currently using.

```
SELECT transactions.transaction_type, 
  transactions.from_acc_id, 
  transactions.to_acc_id,
  transactions.amount,
  dest.title AS "ACCOUNT DESTINATION",
  src.title AS "ACCOUNT SOURCE"
FROM transactions
  LEFT OUTER JOIN account as dest
    ON transactions.to_acc_id = dext.acc_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN account as src
    ON transactions.from_acc_id = src.acc_id
```

For more information on types of joins that are available in most databases, check out [W3Schools SQL Joins page](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: But how do I keep the other results, where from_acc_id is null, please ?

Comment: I missed that requirement. Change those to LEFT OUTER JOIN. I will update.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simply join the table twice. Use table aliases to tell the source account from the target account.

```
SELECT 
  t.transaction_type, 
  t.from_acc_id, 
  t.to_acc_id,
  t.amount,
  from_acc.title AS from_account,
  to_acc.title AS to_account
FROM transactions t
LEFT JOIN account from_acc ON from_acc.acc_id = t.from_acc_id
LEFT JOIN account to_acc ON to_acc.acc_id = t.to_acc_id
```

Comment: But how do I keep the other results, where from_acc_id is null, please ?

Comment: Oops, I missed that. You need outer joins for this, as JNevill has already shown. Sorry.